# Show image with onMouseOver, with image being outside of li-tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, show, onmouseover

I have done this before, but this time I had to move the image outside of the li-tag for the positioning to be how I want it to be. This is how my html code looks, for each 'practicum' I want to have the corresponding 'voorbeeld' to show on hover.

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="menuKop" href="">Practicum 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="menuKop" href="">Practicum 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="menuKop" href="">Practicum 3</a></li>
    <li><a id="menuKop" href="">Practicum 4</a></li>
    <li><a id="menuKop" href="">Practicum 5</a></li>
</ul>

....rest of code....

<img id="voorbeeld1" src="Voorbeeld1.jpg" alt="voorbeeld1" />
```

So I wanted to do that in JavaScript, but I really have no idea how to. Does anyone have a link to a site where this gets explained? Since I think finishing this whole project would be too much to ask. Or maybe just a hint in what I should be looking for.

So far I have been experimenting with an 'onmouseover' function, but I can't get it to work. Any tips/hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using jQuery or plain javascript?

Comment: Tip 1: Your current html is invalid because you have repeated the same `id` on multiple elements. `id` should be unique. Tip 2: One option (not necessarily the best) is to add an attribute to each item that can be hovered, something like `data-img="idofimagehere"`, to specify the id of the img to show, then on mouseover of the item retrieve that attribute...

Comment: oh, yeah how stupid of me!
And I'm using plain javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<ul id="Preview">
    <li><a id="menuKop1" data-image="pic1" href="">Practicum 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="menuKop2" data-image="pic2" href="">Practicum 2</a></li>
</ul>

<img id="pic1" class="hide" src="http://i.imgur.com/vZzIm2t.jpg" alt="voorbeeld1" />
<img id="pic2" class="hide" src="http://i.imgur.com/yQdM1dk.jpg" alt="voorbeeld1" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hide").hide();
$('#Preview a').hover(function() {
    var img = '#'+$(this).data('image');
    $(img).show();
}, function() {
    var img = '#'+$(this).data('image');
    $(img).hide();
} );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nUP7/)

Is that what you want to accomplish?

Comment: you sir, are amazing :) This will help alot!

Comment: Glad I could help. You should read about "data attributes" and the "hover" function if you want to learn more about it.